# What existing materials could be precedence for The Great Wheel of Eurovision?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, planes

[Eurovision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest) has been around since 1956 and DnD just a little bit less.

What existing materials could be used as precedence for an *EPIC* annual contest between bards, where  each of the [Outer planes in the Great Wheel Cosmology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Plane) puts forward one performing  representative (a talented bard), an Over The Top contest occurs, and delegates from all planes vote on the winner?

Part of what this would entail is a contest between bards. Are there existing modules or campaign references that have a contest between bards, including ways to adjudicate besides "roll a skill check"?

The GM has access to both the Pathfinder reference "The Great Beyond" and the 3.5e "Manual of the Planes."  The [Great Wheel Cosmology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Plane) would be preferred over the Pathfinder planar treatment: what existing "outer plane" materials in either system would be of use here?

Asking for a friend, whose players thought it would be fun to create a party that is a band (all the PCs are musicians, not all are bards) and the GM wants to punish them. This question also partially inspired by the recent movie [Eurovision Song Contest: the story of Fire Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest:_The_Story_of_Fire_Saga).

This group primarily plays Pathfinder 1e but other material could be tweaked or adapted to fit.

Comment: I made a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110006/discussion-on-question-by-standardeyre-what-existin-g-materials-could-be-precede) for this question, in case anyone has directions for OP to look in.

Comment: The chat room seems unavailable...